# Excel Data Load using SSIS - Memory used up error

Tags: excel, ssis

I am trying to load data to an excel file using SSIS Package. Please find below the details

- **Source :** SQL Server Table
- **Destination :** Excel File
- **No.of rows**:646K
- **No.of columns**:132

I have deployed the package in the SQL Server Integration Services Catalog and trying to execute it from there.
But the following errors are being thrown:

- Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
- The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with
  error code 0xC0047020.
- SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on
  SRC_MDM_ENTITYDUPLICATE returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The
  component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
  PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
  component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
  There may be error messages posted before this with more information 
  about the failure.

My DFT looks like the following:
[image]

I am using Data Conversion since I am facing some datatype mismatch between Unicode and Non-Unicode characters.

The package is working fine in my local machine with 95-99% resource utilization.
Since I have **deployed the package in production environment**, I **can't do any modifications in the Server Settings**. Also I guess the high resource utilization is creating issue while executing the package in production server.

I tried reducing DefaultBufferMaxRows size and increasing DefaultBufferSize which didn't help me anyhow.

Can somebody help me to optimize my package and fix this issue.
Thanks much in Advance.

Comment: You can avoid using the data conversion by tailoring your source query. For example: `SELECT CAST(Field AS NVARCHAR(1000) As Field FROM Table`. This might allow the package to run successfully

Comment: I tried that as well. Then I am getting error in Source itself.
Column "" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.

Comment: It might be the other way around - I don't know because I don't know what your data types are. Does `SELECT CAST(Field AS VARCHAR(1000)) As Field FROM Table` work? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/149290/

Comment: I tried this. But couldn't resolve the issue. Is there any way by which we could adjust the DFT Buffer effectively?

Comment: Yes that's a good idea.  I guess you could make it smaller which would make your package run slower but might solve the error. You could read this. I'd think by default it wouldn't be so large that it would cause a memory problem. https://intelligentsql.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/ssis-performance-tuning-max-default-buffer-rows/

Comment: You could also just try exporting to text if that is acceptable. 646K is a lot of rows. Who's going to analyse that in Excel?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that blog regarding setting the Max Default Buffer Rows didn't help me anyway.
I am now trying to split the DFT and append the data to same excel sheet.
Do you have some thoughts to share on this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the solution of the error is that the column is not excel in your package, as a solution you will either delete that column from the package or add empty columns

Comment: I am mapping all columns in the table to the excel. I cross checked that again now.